# How to pass "" symbol to Nativeprocess argument?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, air

```
var arg3:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>;
var rescJar:String = File.applicationDirectory.nativePath + "/java/test.jar";
arg3.push("-jar",rescJar,"-n "a string"");
```

"a string" contain 2 separate words.

Answer (score 1):

You can escape "" , by doing this

```
arg3.push("-jar",rescJar,"-n \"a string\"");
```

Comment: Nevermind, it is not possible, I choose passing a single digit instead.

Comment: single digit for a Vector.<String>?!